# How can I create a data frame from a text file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, text-mining

I have a text file.  Each line in the file looks like this, but has a different length:

```
negative فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
positive فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
neutral فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
```

when I use `pandas.read_table` it reads it into one column, I tried converting the file into Excel or CSV, but still converts it into one column

I want it to be a two column data frame where the `negative` in its own column and the rest is in another column.

Comment: Is it always `negative`, or are you just trying to break on the first space?

Comment: Take a look at `pd.read_fwf`

Comment: no 3 values positive, negative, neutral

Comment: still the same,  but it created two empty columns

Answer (score 3):

first read the the whole file into a DataFrame with a single column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.txt', sep='~', header=None)
```

yields:

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
                           0
0  negative aaa bbb ccc  ddd
1           positive qqq vvv
```

now we can parse it like this:

```
In [51]: df[['col1','col2']] = df.pop(0).str.extract(r'^([^\s]+)\s*(.*?)$', expand=True)

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
       col1              col2
0  negative  aaa bbb ccc  ddd
1  positive           qqq vvv
```

or:

```
In [65]: df[['col1','col2']] = df.pop(0).str.split(n=1, expand=True)

In [66]: df
Out[66]:
       col1              col2
0  negative  aaa bbb ccc  ddd
1  positive           qqq vvv
```

Answer (score 3):

You can construct your own parser like:

**Code:**

```
def parse_my_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip().split(' ', 1)
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(parse_my_file('file1'))
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
          0                   1
0  negative  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
1   neutral  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
2  positive  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
```

Comment: Very interesting approach !

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect! I tried splitting before, but never used yield so I was getting multiple errors

Answer (score 2):

Input:

```
from io import StringIO

table = """
negative فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
positive فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
neutral فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
negative فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
negative فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
negative فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
"""
```

Read file:

```
df_in = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(table),widths=[8,1000])  
print(df_in)
```

Output:

```
  Unnamed: 0          Unnamed: 1
0   negative  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
1   positive  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
2    neutral  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
3   negative  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
4   negative  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
5   negative  فينو اهبل ابن اهبل
```